# how can I use ocamlopt instead of ocamldep when using pflag in myocamlbuild?

Tags: ocamlbuild

I have written a `myocamlbuild.ml` after [this manual](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#parametrized-tags) containing the following code in order to not to have to enter in command line some flags each time compiling a test written with `alcotest` like `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package alcotest test_foo.native`

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin

let () =
  dispatch & function
    | Before_rules ->
      pflag ["test_alcotest"] "package" & fun name -> S [A "-use-ocamlfind"; A "-package"; A name]
    | _ -> ()
```

I imagined the command `ocamlbuild test_foo.native` would read the tag I defined in `_tags` file as

```
<test_*.ml>: test_alcotest, package(alcotest)
```

and would call `ocamlc.opt -c -o -use-ocamlfind -package alcotest test_foo.ml`, but it wouldn't; instead it called `ocamldep.opt -use-ocamlfind -package alcotest -pp '-use-ocamlfind -package alcotest' -modules test_foo.ml > test_foo.ml.depends` how can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

There already exists a pre-defined `package(X)` parametrized tag. If you wish to use it, you don't need a `myocamlbuild.ml`; if you wish to override it to give it a different meaning, I would rather recommend using another name to avoid confusion.

If what you want to do is just to pass `-package alcotest`, you don't need a new flag definition. Just use

`<test_*.ml>: package(alcotest)`

and invoke ocamlbuild with `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind`.